# Procedure using Variables and Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

The seed of this project is that our SSRS reporting team submits their reporting requests with  a query and slicers declared as `nvarchar(4000)`. However the table that it is hitting uses `varchar(4000)`. This is causing various issues and I have been charged with creating a procedure that takes the passed variables, converts any `nvarchar` variable to varchar and then returns the results of the query to reporting. Here is an example of the reporting queries as they currently exist.

```
SELECT officeid AS Value1, officename AS Value2, claimcode AS Value3 FROM reporting.vStatus 
WHERE (SubmitDate BETWEEN @DateParameter1 AND @DateParameter2) 
AND (officeid IN (SELECT value FROM string_split(@TextParameter1, ''^'')))
--Variables Being Passed
@DetailQueryTextParameter1 nvarchar(4000)
@DetailQueryTextParameter1=N'1o1o1o1o-1o1o10-1p1p1p6-4r5t5y-q2w3er5^5d4f6t21-5f2sde65rf47-f5df6ffd5-d5e8r7'

@DateParameter1='2022-11-20 00:00:00',
@DateParameter2='2022-11-20 00:00:00'
```

Let's focus on the @TextParameter1 variable as this is a string of alphanumeric IDs designated as nvarchar datatype and delimited by ^. My procedure takes this variable and splits the elements based on the ^ and inserts into a temp table, #slicer, casted as varchar instead of nvarchar. I then use a while statement to add all of theses ids to a new empty string,@var2,  delimited by ^. This much seems to work. Here is a short example

```
@TextParameter1 nvarchar(4000)=NULL,
@DateParameter1 datetime = ' ',
@DateParameter2 datetime = ' ',
@DetailQuery nvarchar(max) = ' '

if @DetailQueryTextParameter1 is not null
SELECT identity(Int,1,1) as rowkey, value into #slicer FROM STRING_SPLIT(cast(@DetailQueryTextParameter1 as varchar(4000)), '^')
declare @var2 varchar(4000) = ' ', @rownum int = 1, @setnum int = (select count(*) from #slicer)
   while @rownum <=@setnum
   Begin
     declare @slice varchar(4000) = (Select value +'^' from #slicer where rowkey = @rownum)
     set @var2 = @var2 +@slice
     set @rownum = @rownum+1
   End
set @var2 = (left(@var2,LEN(@var2)-1))
```

In order for the procedure to handle running the query with the newly converted slices I used the following input

```
declare @slice_w nvarchar(max) = ' WHERE (SubmitDate BETWEEN '+cast(@DetailQueryDateParameter1 as datetime)+' AND ' +cast(@DetailQueryDateParameter2 as datetime)+') AND (officeid IN (SELECT value FROM string_split('+@var2+', ''^'')))'
set @DetailQuery=@DetailQuery+@slice_w
print(@DetailQuery)
print(@var2)
execute sp_executesql @DetailQuery
```

and then I call the procedure using the the following variables

```
EXEC Procedure
@TextParameter1 = N'1o1o1o1o-1o1o10-1p1p1p6-4r5t5y-q2w3er5^5d4f6t21-5f2sde65rf47-f5df6ffd5-d5e8r7'

@DateParameter1='2022-01-01',
@DateParameter2='2022-01-02',
@DetailQuery='SELECT officeid AS Value1, officename AS Value2, claimcode AS Value3 FROM reporting.vStatus '
```

Thank you for your patience up to this point. The problem I run into is when I call this procedure it will return an error in regards to how the @DetailQuery handles variables @var2,@DateParameter1,and @DateParameter2. SELECT value FROM string_split('+@var2+', ''^'') will return a delimited list of ids outside of a string making it so that the query cant read it properly. The date variables return a date/time conversion error, but if I cast them as Varchar or nVarchar they return Jun 1 2022 instead of the expected '2022-01-01'

What do I need to do in order to get the dynamic sql to handle these variables properly? Do I need to encapsulate @var2 in '' ? Do I need to specify a datetime format for the date variables? Do I need to consider adding the variable names to the @DetailQuery when I call the procedure?

Comment: Why not just change everything in your system to use `nvarchar(max)`? Seems you are creating quite a mess to manage and maintain.

Comment: I think if you want assistance you need to trim your question down just to the actual problem you are facing a provide a [mre] i.e. with emphasis on minimal, just the details we need to understand the core issue. I gave up trying to make sense of your question early on, but my impression was I don't need to know all that to solve your actual issue.

Comment: Not sure exactly what specifically needs to be answered here, an observation would be why use nvarchar if your data does not contain unicode, why use an iterative loop when you can probably use string_agg, use convert with the correct date format code to handle dates stored as strings.

Comment: ok, Lets say I have a query I want to pass to the procedure. (Select * from t.status where Date between '@'date1 and '@'date 2 and ID in('@'id)  In this case the date and Id variables are declared within the parameters of the procedure and I pass them like this     EXEC Procedure 1  '@'sql_query = (Select * from t.status where Date between @date1 and '@'date 2 and ID in('@'id)  , '@'date1 = '2022-01-01','@'date 2= '2022-01-02' and '@'id = '5a4s2d5'   When the Procedure  execute sp_executesql '@'Sql_query I get an error saying "Must declare the scalar variable '@'date1 "